# Зачем нужна запись вида posx_desk + 2 - 1

Tags: javascript

Исследуя код одного сайта, наткнулся на строчку:

```
var abs_num = (posy_desk - 1 + 2)*17 + posx_desk + 2 - 1;
```

Стало интересно, зачем отнимать единицу, а затем прибавлять двойку?
Это часть кода какой-то хитрой обработки координат клика по странице (возможно это важно).

Comment: Скорее всего это сделано для облегчения обслуживания кода. Для нас это ничего не значит, а другим разработчикам, работающим с этим кодом, сразу будет понятно в контексте.

Comment: Для меня очевидно только что это плохая практика. Если по коду нельзя понять, почему он так написан, а объясняющих комментариев нет, то он будет непонятен всем, кроме круга посвященных.

Comment: Может быть, дело в том, что `posx_desk` и `posy_desk` имеют до этого момента строковое представление? Но почему бы тогда не использовать обычный унарный плюс?

Comment: Тут ещё интересно, зачем одно и тоже число умножать и прибавлять? Как по мне, это был какой-то ход каких-то мыслей разработчика, которые в последствии не пришли в порядок. `(posy_desk + 1)*18`

Comment: Я бы предположил, что 1 и 2 имеют в данном конкретном коде некий реальный смысл (скажем, -1 преобразует значение из порядкового номера, начинающегося с единицы, в индекс, начинающийся с нуля, а +2 задаёт некое постоянное смещение, например, двухпиксельную границу/отступ).

Comment: Это пример "плохого" кода. Следовало бы вынести эту формулу в отдельную именованую функцию хотя бы, чтобы из названия было понятно, что этот код делает. И магические числа заменить на константы.

Comment: @Byulent обе переменные это результат функции `parseInt()` т.е. там гарантированно целое число(или NaN) и дополнительные преобразования не нужны  
@ArtemGorlachev там разные числа, хотя названия переменных, на мой взгляд, неудачные и это не сразу заметно  
  
А в целом видимо это действительно просто "плохой код", т.к. там ещё много "странного". Эх а я наделся что это какой то хитрый хак:)